# mesh lines on object that I cant hide

Tags: mesh, objects

As you can see, the front bumper has mesh lines on it, even in solid mode, but the fenders on the right have no lines. how do i get rid of the mesh lines?

[image: weird mesh lines]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have the *Wireframe* option enabled in the *Object panel > Viewport Display*:

[image]

Comment: my wireframe is turned off and the lines still appear

Comment: could you please share your file? upload and copy paste the URL: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i fixed it dont worry, appreciate the help however. 

It was an imported .dae file, so there was an extra wireframe ontop of the mesh which i just selected and deleted

Comment: oh ok, fine then  ;)